Blazor WASM Core Hosted Azure Deployment Issue
I recently upgraded from .Net 7 to .Net 8.  My application runs fine locally but when I deploy to Azure, I get two Warnings in the browser console:

MONO_WASM: the version of dotnet.runtime.js is different from the
version of dotnet.js in file dotnet.runtime.8.0.7

and

MONO_WASM: the version of dotnet.native.js is different from the
version of dotnet.js in file dotnet.runtime.8.0.7

and the  error:

Failed to find a valid digest in the integrity attribute for resource
_framework/dotnet.native.wasm with computed SHA-256 integrity.  the resource has been blocked.

I have tried clearing all caches, cleaned and rebuilt the app, manually deleted all obj and bin folders (in the Client, Server and Shared project files).  My application should be targeting 8.0.2.  In the root of the solution I added global.json file that has:
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "8.0.201"
  }
}

I am not sure why it is generating dotnet.runtime.8.0.7 or if that is even the reason for the warnings and errors.  Can anyone provide guidance on how to resolve this?

Did you updated the packages after upgrading to .net 8?

@jason -  Please share your .csproj file.

@jason Try using the latest version of the SDK 8.0.303, which corresponds to the runtime version 8.0.7.

I created a .NET 7 Blazor WASM application and upgraded it to .NET 8.

Updated the packages, deleted the bin and obj folders, build the solution, and deployed it to the Azure App Service.


Failed to find a valid digest in the integrity attribute for resource _framework/dotnet.native.wasm with computed SHA-256 integrity. the resource has been blocked.

To resolve above error clear all NuGet cache storage by following the steps below.
Go To Tools ->NuGet Package Manager -> Manage NuGet for Solution -> setting symbol ->NuGet Package Manager -> General -> Clear All NuGet Storage -> Ok.


Below is my .csproj file.
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="8.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="8.0.2" PrivateAssets="all" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

Before deploying the app to the Azure app service delete the _framework from kudu.
GoTo kudu -> Debug console -> CMD -> site -> wwwroot -> wwwroot ->_framework.

Azure App Service Output:

